# Programmatically set navigation bar color and height in iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

I am very new to swift and am building a navigation view. Below is what i ran into.

[currentView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOzl8.png)

1. The navigation bar background color is only partly yellow. How can I also make the section above it also yellow?

[section should be yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uLDV.png)

Below is the code that I used in my `viewController`. I also tried in the `navigation controller` but it doesn't work.

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow`

2. How to set the height of the navigation bar? The search button (`navigationItem.titleView`) is right in the middle of the navigation bar and I want to give it more space by setting the navigation bar height. The code below is what I tried but doesn't work :(

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height = 50`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to changed the status bar color as well. you can done this using below extension of UIApplication

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

use above extension like this :

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .yellow
```

**for iOS 13 and above**

use UINavigationController extension to change status bar color :

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func setStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        let statusBarFrame: CGRect
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            statusBarFrame = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero
        } else {
            statusBarFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        }
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: statusBarFrame)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
    }
}
```

```
navigationController?.setStatusBar(backgroundColor: .yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. However is there a way to increase the height of the navigation bar only? (The yellow area in. the first pic)

Comment: @LoLo i tried a lot to increase the height of navigation bar but i can't done it. once it will be done i'll ping you. thanks

Comment: @LoLo instead of increasing the size of navigation bar i suggest you to just hide the navigation bar and add `uiview` and all other stuff on it to create your search bar from interface builder or `xib` file.

It's bit tricky process to add subview in navigation bar for increasing height and giving color to it so just hide it And when there is no navigation bar, you don't need to write the above stuff in your code. Just assign the color to uiview.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!